# How to generate qwc file and how to sync my data with Quickbooks through web connector?

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I have Quickbooks Desktop Enterprise Solution 18.0 Trial version R5P and QB web connector 2.2.0.80.

I am completely new to Quickbooks. I already go through this link ([How to create a .qwc file for QuickBooks Web Connector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420766/how-to-create-a-qwc-file-for-quickbooks-web-connector)). i  generated .qwc file and tried connect with quickbooks through web connector and I got a error
[QWC1501: The new application was not added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnt9d.png)

This is my qwc file content:

Please guide me if there is anything wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QBXML>
<AppName>WCWebService</AppName>
<AppID>
</AppID>
<AppURL>http://loaclhost/QBWebService.asmx</AppURL>
<AppDescription>A Short Description for WCWebservice</AppDescription>
<AppSupport>http://localhost/QBWebService.asmx?wsdl</AppSupport>
<UserName>Nagarajan</UserName>
<OwnerID>7ff3fabf-1c2c-490b-bff1-91148fc8d9a8</OwnerID>
<FileID>81d4dad8-a5dc-4b79-8c09-be679c9d8e28</FileID>
<QBType>QBFS</QBType>
<Scheduler>
<RunEveryNMinutes>2</RunEveryNMinutes>
</Scheduler>
</QBXML>`
```

Log file says that

```
Log file initialized at Sunday, April 8, 2018 - 10:10 AM UTC  
Timestamp format used: YYYYMMDD.HH:MM:SS UTC
QBWebConnector 2.2 has been initialized with its logging status to level = 
DEBUG.
Please restart QBWebConnector for any change in log level to take effect. 
Use file menu to clear log.

20180408.10:10:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to 
False
20180408.10:10:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : 
********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20180408.10:10:43 UTC   : QWCReader.ParseQWC() : Contents of QWC file: -
<QBXML>
<AppName>WCWebService</AppName>
<AppID></AppID>
<AppURL>http://localhost/WCWebService.asmx</AppURL>
<AppDescription>A Short Description for WCWebservice</AppDescription>
<AppSupport>http://localhost/QBWebService.asmx?wsdl</AppSupport>
<UserName>Nagarajan</UserName>
<OwnerID>47c49092-071c-4edb-97a3-2715ab6325f8</OwnerID>
<FileID>1938435f-db77-40d2-8392-64ab98f5081c</FileID>
</QBXML>
20180408.10:10:45 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.ReadQWC(string 
fileName) : Unexpected root doc: QBXML

QBWC1051: The new application was not added
20180408.10:10:45 UTC   :  : ~SingleInstanceHandler() - usingInstanceChannel 
= false. Returning without any Registry key delete or unmarshalling.
```

This is my code for Customer add.

```
    string strRequestXML ="";
        XmlDocument inputXMLDoc = null;

        // CustomerQuery
        inputXMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
        inputXMLDoc.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0",null, null));
        inputXMLDoc.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateProcessingInstruction("qbxml", "version=\"4.0\""));

        XmlElement qbXML = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("QBXML");
        inputXMLDoc.AppendChild(qbXML);
        XmlElement qbXMLMsgsRq = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("QBXMLMsgsRq");
        qbXML.AppendChild(qbXMLMsgsRq);
        qbXMLMsgsRq.SetAttribute("onError", "stopOnError");
            XmlElement CustomerAddRq = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("CustomerAddRq");
            qbXMLMsgsRq.AppendChild(CustomerAddRq);
        CustomerAddRq.SetAttribute("requestID", "1");
        XmlElement custAdd = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("CustomerAdd");
        CustomerAddRq.AppendChild(custAdd);
        custAdd.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("Name","Naga"));
        custAdd.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("FirstName", "Nagarajan"));
        custAdd.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("MiddleName", ""));
        custAdd.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("LastName", "varatharajan"));
        XmlElement BillAddress = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("BillAddress");
        custAdd.AppendChild(BillAddress);
        BillAddress.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("Addr1", "7/78"));
        BillAddress.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("City", "Chennai"));
        BillAddress.AppendChild(inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("State", "TN"));            
        XmlElement maxReturned = inputXMLDoc.CreateElement("MaxReturned");
        CustomerAddRq.AppendChild(maxReturned).InnerText="1";
        strRequestXML = inputXMLDoc.OuterXml;
        req.Add(strRequestXML);
```

Comment: What does the log say? What version/year/edition of QuickBooks? What does your code look like?

Comment: Thank you @KeithPalmerJr. I updated version and log file. Please review it and guide me if there is anything wrong.

Comment: @NagarajanVaratharajan I'm also not able to figure it out how to create .QWC file? Can you please help me regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

Your .QWC file is invalid.

You can use the `XML Validator` tool included with the QuickBooks SDK to verify this. You may also want to refer to other .QWC-related questions on StackOverflow, which show properly constructed .QWC files. For example:

- [How to create a .qwc file for QuickBooks Web Connector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420766/how-to-create-a-qwc-file-for-quickbooks-web-connector)

If you read the log file, this is pretty obvious. You can see this:

`QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.ReadQWC(string 
fileName) : Unexpected root doc: QBXML`

Fix your .QWC file (specifically the root node) so that it meets the specification.

Comment: Thank you @KeithPalmerJr. As per you suggestion i created connection  using qwc file through the web connector. I tried sync data it shows error  in the status bar that is Description:
Error message received from application via getLastError(): Error! and i will include log file and code file. Please review it.

Comment: If you have a question about a totally new thing (e.g. anything that's NOT about creating a .QWC file) then you need to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I see three things:

- QBXML should be QBWCXML
- you have a quote after the closing QBXML
- You have spelled `localhost` incorrectly in the AppURL element.

But looking again at the responses to Keith's answer, it looked like that fixed your problem, so you should mark it as correct.